# Get sum of 3 large values out of 4 in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate the best 3 marks of class test assignment and get the sum of them in Excel. I am wondering what would be the formula for this. For the reference I have added an image below:

[image: sample spreadsheet]

**I want among (17, 1, 19, 20) I get (17, 19, 20) and the sum (17+19+20) = 56 put it in final marks column**

Comment: Look into LARGE() function

Comment: thanks. I have looked up on this.. but couldnt figure out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the LARGE() function to get the largest, second largest, third largest values and sum them all up.

```
=SUM(LARGE(B3:F3,1),LARGE(B3:F3,2),LARGE(B3:F3,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you have only 4 items, it can be calculated like this

```
=SUM(B3:E3) - MIN(B3:E3)
```

Comment: Very true! Easiest

Answer (score 1):

I use this to get best 4 out of 6:

```
=SUM(LARGE(N4:S4,{1,2,3,4}))
```

which for your three becomes:

```
=SUM(LARGE(B3:F3,{1,2,3}))
```

But I don't enter it as an array formula, works just fine dragged down as necessary.